# How to call api on recyclerview item click event in MVVM structure?

Tags: android, api, mvvm, android-recyclerview, onitemclick

I am creating Adapter (for Recyclerview) using MVVM structure in Android, where I have created ViewModel class for each item of recyclerview.
now I want to call an API on Onclick() method of recyclerview in android.

I cannot call API in recyclerview's itemViewModel so i have to call the api using Activity view Model.

what is the best way to do this?

i am following this example on git:
https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvvm

Comment: which API please explain more... please write more details about the problem.

Comment: @ItzikSamara i want to call my web service on item click. but the problem is that the code to call web service is inside ActivityViewModel.

example:https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvvm/ui/feed/blogs/BlogAdapter.java

 the way it has open the browser on onclick.

Comment: Pass the view model object from your activity to your adapter and then call whatever api you want, alternatively you can use something like event bus and post events to receive in view model.

Comment: @RoshaanFarrukhI have injected the adapter in activity. but cannot pass anything as a constructor. 
you can refer the structure from the above GitHub link

Comment: @RoshaanFarrukh thanks for suggestion I passed activity reference in the adapter and it worked